# Infinit loop when calling Bundle.main.loadNibNamed from awakeFromNib

Tags: ios

Can you not call loadNibNamed in awaikeFromNib?

Note the current view, with the awakeFromNib method is in the same Nib but it is not the same view.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {

    let otherView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyViews", owner: self, options: nil)![2] as! OtherView

...
```

Comment: What is the class of the root view in your .xib file? It looks like you set the class of the root view to the same class which loads this nib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not tell `loadNibNamed` To load a specific view from the nib. It loads all of the views. You are accessing a specific view by subscripting the views array, but all views have been loaded to allow you to do this.

This means that you are triggering `awakeFromNib` again, which loads the nib, which triggers `awakeFromNib` and so on.

So the short answer is, as you have found, loading the source nib in `awakeFromNib` will result in an infinite loop.